# Cannot pass second variable to isoloated scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create my own directive that has to get to parameters: requests and currentUser.

The requests parameter succesfully passed to the ditective but the currentUser is not.

The currentUser is defiend in app.run in the $rootScope.

I have to note that the currentUser is accessible in the 'dashboard.html'

The code is this:

The directive:

```
app.directive('requestsTableForBuyer', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'AE',
    'templateUrl': '../directives/requestsTables/requestsTableForBuyer.html',
    'scope': {
      requests: "=",
      currentUser: "="
    },
    'controller': function($scope, $timeout, toaster) {
      console.log($scope.currentUser);
    }
});
```

The app.run:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.currentUser = "ori";
});
```

The dashboard.html (just the relevant part):

```
<requests-table-for-buyer requests="requests" currentUser="currentUser"></requests-table-for-buyer>
```

What might be the problem and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the problem of not using the correct bindings and also currentUser element is wrong in the HTML. It should be live below.

`<requests-table-for-buyer requests="requests" current-user="currentUser"></requests-table-for-buyer>`

Change your scopes bindings like below

`app.directive('requestsTableForBuyer', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'AE',
    'templateUrl': '../directives/requestsTables/requestsTableForBuyer.html',
    'scope': {
      requests: "=",
      currentUser: "=?"
    },
    'controller': function($scope, $timeout, toaster) {
      console.log($scope.currentUser);
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're referring to it camel cased when it should be snake-cased in the html:

```
<requests-table-for-buyer current-user="currentUser" ...>
```

Like so.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML code like below, it will definitely work

```
<requests-table-for-buyer requests="requests" current-user="currentUser"></requests-table-for-buyer>
```

Because Camel-case is treated as dash representation in angular directives inputs